# Does syncfs wait until disc write finished?

Tags: c, linux, io

Does the new syncfs system call wait for disc write completion before returning, like in case of fsync?
Also, if after modifying file, is calling syncfs for this file descriptor also update the containing directoy entry?

Comment: What's the difference between `syncfs` and `fsync`?

Comment: syncfs write all buffered data and metadata of the partition containing the file descriptor, fsync only write modified data and metadata of the file descriptor.

Comment: Interesting, thanks.  That makes `syncfs` a potentially very expensive call.  Presumably this flushing impacts every process with dirty data in that partition whether they like it or not?  Or is just limited to files opened by the `syncfs`-ing process?

Comment: @Duck it is better than sync which syncs all mounted partition. Also in some cases, we want to sync the partition once after modifying many files in the partition, so calling fsync on each of this file maybe more expensive than a single syncfs (if there is no other process modifying the partition)

Answer (score 5):

syncfs writes out all dirty pages from the superblock on down.  Disks may have write caching, so this does not guarantee that all data has been saved. You could, for example, turn off power without still calling shutdown.

Comment: Is there way to guarantee / check disc write caching is done?

Comment: Send a STOP UNIT command to the disk.  It will flush its cache and spin down the disk.  There are some barrier commands, but not all disks support them.

Comment: From the kernel, you create a SCSI CDB and use a SCSI command call.  User space is generally not permitted to directly access disks, but you could use system to execute sg_start.