# What is the difference between fsync and syncfs?

Tags: c, linux, filesystems, posix, unistd.h

What is the difference between fsync and syncfs ?

```
int syncfs(int fd);
int fsync(int fd);
```

The manpage for fync says the following :

> fsync()  transfers  ("flushes")  all modified in-core data of (i.e., modified buffer cache pages
>          for) the file referred to by the file descriptor fd to the disk device (or other permanent stor‐
>          age  device)  so  that all changed information can be retrieved even after the system crashed or
>          was rebooted.  This includes writing through or flushing a disk  cache  if  present.   The  call
>          blocks  until  the  device  reports  that  the transfer has completed.  It also flushes metadata
>          information associated with the file (see stat(2)).

The manpage for syncfs says the following:

> sync() causes all buffered modifications to file metadata and data to be written to the underly‐
>          ing filesystems.
>
> syncfs() is like sync(), but synchronizes just the filesystem containing file referred to by the
>          open file descriptor fd.

For me both seem equal. They are sychronizing the file referred by the filedescriptor and the associated metadata.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

First, [`fsync()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fsync.html) (and [`sync()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sync.html)) are POSIX-standard functions while [`syncfs()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sync.2.html) is Linux-only.

So availability is one big difference.

From the [POSIX standard for `fsync()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fsync.html):

> The `fsync()` function **shall request** that all data for the open file
>   descriptor named by `fildes` is to be transferred to the storage
>   device associated with the file described by `fildes`. The nature of
>   the transfer is implementation-defined. The `fsync()` function shall
>   not return until the system has completed that action or until an
>   error is detected.

Note that it's just a request.

From [the POSIX standard for `sync()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sync.html):

> The `sync()` function shall cause all information in memory that
>   updates file systems to be **scheduled for writing** out to all file
>   systems.
>
> The writing, although scheduled, is not necessarily complete upon
>   return from `sync()`.

Again, that's not something guaranteed to happen.

[The Linux man page for `syncfs()` (and `sync()`) states](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sync.2.html)

> `sync()` causes all pending modifications to filesystem metadata and
>   cached file data to be written to the underlying filesystems.
>
> `syncfs()` is like `sync()`, but synchronizes just the filesystem
>   containing file referred to by the open file descriptor `fd`.

Note that *when* the function returns is unspecified.

[The **Linux** man page for `fsync()` states](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fsync.2.html):

> `fsync()` transfers ("flushes") all modified in-core data of (i.e.,
>   modified buffer cache pages for) the file referred to by the file
>   descriptor `fd` to the disk device (or other permanent storage device)
>   so that all changed information can be retrieved even if the system
>   crashes or is rebooted.  This includes writing through or flushing a
>   disk cache if present.  The call blocks until the device reports that
>   the transfer has completed.
>
> As well as flushing the file data, `fsync()` also flushes the metadata
>   information associated with the file (see inode(7)).
>
> Calling `fsync()` does not necessarily ensure that the entry in the
>   directory containing the file has also reached disk.  For that an
>   explicit `fsync()` on a file descriptor for the directory is also
>   needed.

Note that the guarantees Linux provides for `fsync()` are much stronger than those provided for `sync()` or `syncfs()`, and by POSIX for both `fsync()` and `sync()`.

In summary:

1. POSIX `fsync()`:  "please write data for this file to disk"
2. POSIX `sync()`: "write all data to disk when you get around to it"
3. Linux `sync()`: "write all data to disk (when you get around to it?)"
4. Linux `syncfs()`: "write all data for the filesystem associated with this file to disk (when you get around to it?)"
5. Linux `fsync()`: "write all data and metadata for this file to disk, and don't return until you do"

Note that the Linux man page doesn't specify when `sync()` and `syncfs()` return.

Comment: For differences between fsync and syncfs, please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20708941/does-syncfs-wait-until-disc-write-finished

Comment: It seems that even Linux fsync() has a caveat that even if the function returns success, an error may have occurred and the data were not written. As described here https://lwn.net/Articles/752063/

Comment: I believe #3 in your summary is incorrect. See @user869887's answer about sync(2), which specifies that Linux does wait for I/O completions (https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sync.2.html).

Unless there is some difference that I'm not understanding?

Comment: @GeminiDakota That man page states "`sync()` is always successful."  If it's always successful, it can't be waiting for I/O completions.

Comment: The Linux Programming Interface Page 241: In the Linux implementation, `sync()` returns only after all data has been transferred to the disk device (or at least to its cache). However, SUSv3 permits an implementation of `sync()` to simply schedule the I/O transfer and return before it has completed.

Answer (score 12):

I think the current answer is not complete. For Linux:

> According to the standard specification (e.g., POSIX.1-2001), `sync()`
>   schedules the writes, but may return before the actual writing is
>   done. However Linux waits for I/O completions, and thus `sync()` or
>   `syncfs()` provide the same guarantees as `fsync` called on every file
>   in the system or filesystem respectively.

and

> Before version 1.3.20 Linux did not wait for I/O to complete before
>   returning.

This is mentioned on the [`sync(2)` page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sync.2.html) in the "notes" and "bugs" sections.

Comment: You are right. Where are the upvotes, people?